# How to solve conditions on UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update in test_t1 using test_t2, with conditions like IF status column in test_t2 is 'Y' then update 1 in test_t1.sign_val or 'N' then update 0 in test_t1.sign_val.
  And also another condition like if status column contain two 'Y' then update 1 or two'N' then update 0 in sign_value in test_t1.

```
 test_t1                 test_t2
CATAG   SIGN_VAL        CATAG STATU
----- ----------        ----- -----
AB             0        AB    Y
BC             0        AB    Y
CD             0        BC    Y
                        CD    Y       
                        BC    N



---   this is the code i try
    MERGE INTO test_t1 t1
     USING test_t2 t2
    ON (t1.catagory = t2.catagory)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET t1.sign_val = CASE t2.status 
                                 WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
                                 WHEN 'N' THEN 0
```

Comment: And one "N" and one "Y"?

Comment: That will be update like same way update 1 for  one 'Y' and 0 for one 'N'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with some conditions.  It would look something like this:

```
update test_t1 t1
    set sign_val = (select (case when sum(case when t2.status = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > sum(case when t2.status = 'N' then 1 else 0 end)
                                 then 1
                                 else 0
                             end)
                    from test_t2 t2
                    where t2.catag = t1.catag
                   );
```

This sets `sign_val` to "1" if there are more "Y"s than "N"s.  That seems like a reasonable interpretation of your question.  But the logic can clearly be modified if that isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you please tell what is sum keyword in case?

Comment: @Naveen . . . What do you mean?  It is a `sum()` as an aggregation `sum()` on the expression which is a `case` expression.

Comment: sorry am new to oracle, so suddently i didnt get this aggregate function in case..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` as following:

```
Merge into test_t1 t1
Using (select catagary,
Sum(case when status = 'Y' then 1 end) as ycount,
Sum(case when status = 'N' then 1 end) as ncount,
Min(status) min_status
From test_t2
Group by catagary) t2
On (t1.catagary = t2.catagary)
When matched then 
Update set
t1.sign_val = case when t2.ycount >= 2
                   then 1
                   when t2.ncount >= 2
                   then 0
                   when t2.min_status = 'N'
                   then 0
                   Else 1 end
```

[Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/040b2/6)

Cheers!!

Comment: Ok, That was not clear to me.. Now updated the answer. Please check.